# smallest algebra generated by ring

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\Omega\neq \emptyset$ and $\mathcal E$ be a ring in $\Omega$ and $\mathcal R_0 := \mathcal E\cup \{E^c:E\in\mathcal E\}$. Show that $\mathcal R_0$ is the smallest algebra in $\Omega$ containing the ring $\mathcal E$, i.e. $\mathcal R_0=\mathcal R_0(\mathcal E)$.

I have been able to show that $\mathcal R_0$ is indeed an algebra, but I'm not able to show that it really is the smallest one containing $\mathcal E$.

The inclusion $\mathcal R_0(\mathcal E)\subset \mathcal R_0$ is trivial since $\mathcal E\subset\mathcal R_0$ by definition and $\mathcal R_0(\mathcal E)=\bigcap_{\mathcal E\subset\mathcal A, \mathcal A\mathrm{\ algebra}}\mathcal A$.

My attempt to prove the inclusion $\mathcal R_0\subset\mathcal R_0(\mathcal E)$ failed, though:

Let $A\in\mathcal R_0$, then we either have $A\in\mathcal E$ or $A\in\{E^c|E\in\mathcal E\}$. If $A\in\mathcal E$ it is clear that $A\in\mathcal R_0(\mathcal E)$. What I am not able to show is that if $A\in\{E^c|E\in\mathcal E\}$ the inclusion $A\in\mathcal R_0(\mathcal E)$ holds.

Does anyone know a way to show this last part? Or a different way to prove the statement? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: If $A \in \mathcal R_0$, then, as $\mathcal R_0$ is an algebra, we have $A^c \in \mathcal R_0$.

Comment: so either $A\in\mathcal E$ or $A^c\in\mathcal E$ and hence $A\in\mathcal R_0(\mathcal E)$ as $\mathcal R_0(\mathcal E)$ is an algebra.

Comment: @dinosaur: Exactly.